# Catch keypress inside a BrowserWindow even if there are multiple BrowserView elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an Electron app with a `BrowserWindow` which contains `index.html` for the app UI, and multiple `BrowserView` elements:

```
browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: width, height: height, frame: false });
browserWindow.webContents.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

var bv = new BrowserView({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: false }});
browserWindow.setBrowserView(bv);
```

I'd like to have keyboard shorcuts, such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> from **everywhere inside the app**.

- `globalShortcut` is not ok here because it applies to *all processes* currently running. As an example, the following shortcut will be caught even if another application than the Electron app has the focus (for example `notepad.exe`)

  ```
  globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+X', () => {
      console.log('CommandOrControl+X is pressed')
  })
  ```
- This method is not ok, because it only works if `index.html` has the focus, but **not if a `BrowserView` has the focus**:

  ```
  browserWindow.webContents.on('before-input-event', (event, input) => {
      if (input.control && input.key.toLowerCase() === 'x') {
          ...
      }
  ```

**Question: how to register a keyboard shortcut for the current Electron app window, working if `index.html` has the focus but also if a `BrowserView` has focus?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: we have to run this code for each `BrowserView`'s `webContents`:

```
bv.webContents.on('before-input-event', (event, input) => {
    if (input.control && input.key.toLowerCase() === 'x') {
        ...
    }
```